# Pytube code works on PC but not on iPhone

Tags: python, ios, pytube

I was trying to make a youtube video downloader for my phone with pytube and wrote a super simple code for it:

```
from pytube import YouTube



yt = YouTube(str(input("Put in your youtube Link: ")))

ys = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()

ys.download()
print("Done")
```

It works fine on my PC but on my iPhone it always spits out the error: urllib.error.HTTPError : HTTP Error 404: Not found. Im using the Python3IDE app and i imported the pytube module. Does anyone know if there's a way to make this work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Usually this problem exists in phone compilers. Note also that the 404 error can even be due to a regional problem of access and lack of access to the filter breaker.